# in android native, Mediacodec.dequeueInputBuffer don't return

Tags: android, native, android-mediacodec

everyone,

When I am developing the android native problem, I come across a problem.

I write a program that using the native mediacodec the encode the yuv file(using the hardware H264 encoder).

when I follow the normal flow(from java layer to call the test code), it works well.

But when I just make the test code into exec file.(using include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)),then push the exec file onto android board, run ./test, it is running the below code, and don't return:

```
err = mCodec->dequeueInputBuffer( &indexInBuffer, -1 );
```

anyone have come across this problem? Please help me, it confused me such a long long time.

May it be a problem of authority??

Answer (score 1):

The last Parameter of the dequeueInputBuffer function specifies the timeout in microseconds. According to the documentation, a negative timeout indicates "infinite". Use a timeout >= 0, and the function will return.

Comment: Although this is true, I am wondering what the potential causes for it are. In what conditions would the codec timeout (or take an enormous amount of time) to provide an input buffer to be written to?

Comment: The codec may decide to buffer some data before it actually starts providing output buffers. This means you might very well have to queue several input buffers before you can dequeue any output buffer. Codecs may also provide several output buffers for one single input buffer. I am writing an app that encodes audio, and I was always wondering why there were gaps in the recording. Turned out the codec was generating 2-3 output buffers per queued input buffer.

Comment: I guess the question is about getting input buffer , I understand your explanation for output buffer; but what causes delay in getting index for input buffer